# How to search specific key values within a dictionary and remove duplicates in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove duplicates from a dictionary. I have it close but what I've realized is, I want to allow duplicates in one set of key values but not allow duplicates in another set of key values.

Also, I have a hard time splitting the dictionary into two and then searching for dupes in the second list because then the numbers don't correspond to each other anymore and are basically meaningless, so that option won't work.

At the moment, my dictionary consists of 3 keys, one for "Item Name", one for "Item URL" and one for "Item Quantity".

I would like to search *only* "Item Name" or "Item URL" for duplicates while ignoring "Item Quantity" as it's allowed to have duplicates.

Once a duplicate is found, I'd want it to remove the whole set of keys/key values for the item duplicate found (say it finds a duplicate in the keys "Item Name", once found, I want it to remove all three (Item Name, Item URL, Item Quantity) for that specific duplicate. How would I go about this?

```
Qualified_Items = {'Item Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'Item Quantity': ['24', '12', '7', '34', '24', '9', '7'], 'Item URL': ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url1']}

No_Dupe_Dicts = {}

for dict in Qualified_Items:
    for k in dict.items():
        if k[0] in No_Dupe_Dicts:
            if Item_Trade_URL[1] not in No_Dupe_Dicts[k[0]]:
                No_Dupe_Dicts[k[0]].append(k[1])
        else:
            No_Dupe_Dicts[k[0]]=[k[1]]

pprint.pprint(No_Dupe_Dicts)
```

This returns the correct answer, but it has removed all of the duplicate "Item Quantity" values that I need.

Recap - Search keyvalues "Item Name" for duplicates ignoring all other keys listed in the dictionary. Once duplicate key is found, all 3 keys pertaining to the duplicated item is removed from the dictionary.

I am still a bit new to all of this, but am quickly learning.

I am using Python 3 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: First line appears to be a syntax error. Wondering how it worked for you. It could be `qualified_items = {'Item Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'Item Quantity': ['24', '12', '7', '34', '24', '9', '7'], 'Item URL': ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url1']}`

Comment: I wrote out the dictionary line by hand because in my actual code it's putting dictionaries together from multiple smaller dictionaries. Since I didn't want to post that giant block of code, I just wrote out a example dictionary. Thanks though I appreciate it, i'm mainly needing to figure out how to focus my checks on a single keyvalue instead of all 3 when I check for dupes.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I will be helpful if you can give the expected output for `Qualified_Items` after removing duplicates.

Comment: Provide input and output samples. From the code you posted, it looks like you don't really get what a dictionary really is in Python.